# Errror in outputting CSV with Django?

Tags: python, django, export-to-csv

I am trying to output my model as a CSV file.It is working fine with small data in model and it is very slow with large data.And secondly there are some error in outputting a model as CSV.My logic which I am using is:

```
def some_view(request):
    # Create the HttpResponse object with the appropriate CSV header.
    response = HttpResponse(content_type='text/csv')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="news.csv"'
    writer = csv.writer(response)
    news_obj = News.objects.using('cms').all()
    for item in news_obj:
        #writer.writerow([item.newsText])
        writer.writerow([item.userId.name])

    return response
```

and the error which I am facing is:

> UnicodeEncodeError :--
>   'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-6: ordinal not in
>   range(128)

and further it says:-

> The string that could not be encoded/decoded was: عبدالله الحذ

Comment: the error is with your encoding, pass encoding format in the content disposition like UTF-8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace line

```
writer.writerow([item.userId.name])
```

with:

```
writer.writerow([item.userId.name.encode('utf-8')])
```

Before saving unicode string to a file you must encode it in some encoding. Most system use `utf-8` by default, so it's a safe choice.

Comment: it is not working for large files any reason if u know sir?

Comment: What do you mean? what error do you receive? How large is the file?

Comment: Thanks for the concern i have implemented that using streaming large CSV files

Answer (score 0):

From the error, The write content of csv file is like ASCII character. So decode the character.

```
>>>u'aあä'.encode('ascii', 'ignore')
'a'
```

Can fix this error from ignoring the ASCII character:

```
writer.writerow([item.userId.name.encode('ascii', 'ignore')])
```